# Get clients time as TIMESTAMP from PHP to SQL

Tags: php, sql, time, client

I am looking to find out how I can get clients local time as the timestamp when submit is pressed on my form.

My server is hosted in the US and I am in Ireland, have checked if I can change the time but this isn't possible as its a shared server.
Can anyone point in the right direction to do the above?

Comment: Add a hidden field to the form and use JavaScript to populate that field with the current timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the time zone in your PHP code using the `date_default_timezone_set()`.
The `date_default_timezone_set()` function sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in the script.
Then use the `date()` to generate the current date/time in PHP and insert that date/time in the database table.